# how to tell gradle to download a file from my local computer in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

I'm working on an app with flutter, I recently downloaded the latest version of flutter and the latest version of flutter.

the versions are:

**Flutter:** 1.17.5

**Gradle:** 6.5.1

i tried to run an app i was working on using an older version of flutter and gradle and it was giving me errors about some missing files so i kept trying and gradle downloaded all files except one of them, this file is so big for the android studio built in downloader that it can't download it and it's always failing to do so, so i manually downloaded the file, the file is **kotlin-compiler-26.5.0.jar** and the size of it is about 23.4 MB, so now i have the file on my local computer.

my question is: can i tell gradle to take the file from local computer instead of the internet, or better yet where should i put this file?

P.S.: i know the problem might be becausse the internet connection i have, but there's nothing else i can do about that.

**THANKS**

Comment: @JideGuru I'm on windows

Comment: Okay let me see if i can get the folder. But you should check your user folder if there's a .gradle folder in there

Comment: yes there is a .gradle folder in there, but i don't know where to put the file.

Comment: try `.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.external.com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.5.0` you'll see a folder in there, open the folder and paste your file there

Comment: yeah i'll try it right now, thanks man

Comment: @JideGuru it worked, thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Happy Fluttering!